# mysql average count from related table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables:

#### users table

list of users

#### stories

list of stories - multiple stories per user

I want to know the average number of stories a user has.  (not a specific user, for all users)

Expected results: 2.3 average stories per user

Tried:

select avg(w) from (select count(distinct user_id) as w from stories group by user_id) a;
above ran but didn't seem correct

also:

SELECT user_id, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stories w WHERE w.user_id = u.user_id ) as TotalStories FROM user u;

returned average stories for each user, not average for overall

Comment: select
avg(`w`) from
(select count(distinct user_id) as w from stories group by user_id) a;

Comment: above ran but didn't seem correct

Comment: SELECT user_id, 
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM stories w
WHERE w.user_id = u.user_id
) as TotalStories
FROM user u;

Comment: put this in your question  by editing your question so every member can have look into this.

Comment: above doesn't do an average just returns average of entire list of users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to know the number of stories per user:

```
select count(s.id) as n
from users u left outer join stories s on u.id = s.user_id
group by u.id
```

Then just apply `avg` to that:

```
select avg(n)
from (
    select count(s.id) as n
    from users u left outer join stories s on u.id = s.user_id
    group by u.id
) as dt
```

Comment: this gave me 'Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: @jhanifen: Sorry, forgot the "as dt" bit.

Comment: this also worked and was great to have two separate queries that returned the same results as a test.

Comment: any thoughts on which was is better or faster?

Comment: @jhanifen: You'd have to profile them. Using `avg` tells the database your precise intent and that's usually your best bet; in general, the more you can tell the database about what exactly you're trying to do the better it can give you exactly what you want as quickly as possible. If you want an average, ask the database for one; if you want a standard deviation, ask the database for one (`stddev_pop`), ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) AS totalusers, SUM(storycount) AS totalstories, SUM(storycount) / COUNT(userid) AS average_stories
FROM (
    SELECT users.id AS userid, COUNT(stories.id) AS storycount
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN stories ON (users.id = stories.user_id)
    GROUP BY users.id
) AS child
```

Inner query does the per-user story counting. Outer query counts the total users, total stories, and the stories per user average.